# Best way to use Sonar in a large team?

Tags: java, eclipse, sonarqube

I am currently deploying Sonar for a large(50+) development team with a substantial java code base. I could not work out an effective work process with Sonar. Here are some issues:

1. If developers scan their code using sonar-runner against the central server:

   1. They need to upload ton's of code, although they are interested in a small set of classes
   2. They clash as they upload the same file with different versions
2. Running Sonar locally, using Eclipse plug-in, again raises issues:

   1. It analyzes all code, while you are only interested in specific files
   2. It has no knowledge of the false positives defined on server - so you are swamped with unnecessary warnings
3. I integrated Sonar in the nightly build, but then a developer receives code issues only at T+1. Worse - the developer checks-in un-scanned code.

How can we achieve a workflow that:

- Allows developer to analyze **specific** code BEFORE check-in
- Does not burden developer by "re-opening" false positives an ignored files
- Developers do not "over-write" each other's analysis on un-committed files
- Integrated with the standard build (Maven, SVN) to monitor what is checked in

Comment: Q : When you say large code base - is it 100 projects with 50 Java files each or 1 project with 5000 java files ?

Comment: This [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11266854/can-sonar-plugin-exclusions-be-configured-for-local-analysis-without-a-local-ser) might help. Basically use local PMD and Checkstyle

Comment: @Pulak - 8 projects each consisting of several hundred classes. The answer quoted does not address my issue, but thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What we are doing in our team, is that we have configured Jenkins to call sonar each time code is committed on the common SVN.

On Jenkins we have thousand of small projects (less than 20 classes) and each programmer can create its own Dashboard page with the projects he is interested in.

Moreover, you can set up Jenkins with Maven so that project depends on each other. It prevent from a full rebuild if the change only happens in one of the view project (often latest in build process).

Comment: This might be the right answer. Can you clarify:
- Does this meand that Developer will usually check-in first, and receive Sonar input later that day?
- Why do you need so many small projects? is it related to your specific environment or is it due to some jenkins-sonar limitation?

Comment: 1. Yes, developers check-in and receive sonar results as soon as they are evaluated (from 5 min to 1 hour later). 2. The number of small projects is only related to our environment not to sonar or jenkins.

Comment: What we have done, for checkstyle for instance, is that you can set up the configuration as a Maven dependency of the Maven Checkstyle plugin. Then developers can run locally checkstyle rules with the project specific configuration before checking-in. I guess that the same pattern could be set up for findbugs/sonar/pmd maven plugins.